# how to set option of ffmpeg with libx264, I,P,B order?

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, libx264

I'm looking for a option of ffmpeg with libx264.
I want to operate it, like a hardware encoder with ordering of the fixed frame type.

IBBPBBPBBPBBPBB..IBBPBBPBBPBBP..IBBPBBP...

Please, give me a advice.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    INFILE=$1
    IFILE=$1.ts

    OPT_CRF="-g 120 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -bf 2"
    VAL_CBR="20000k"
    OPT_COMMON="-c:v libx264 -b:v $VAL_CBR -minrate $VAL_CBR -maxrate $VAL_CBR -g 60"

    ffmpeg -i $IFILE -vf crop=1920:1088:0:16 $OPT_COMMON -acodec copy ${INFILE}.1.ts
    ffmpeg -i $IFILE -vf crop=1920:1088:1920:16 $OPT_COMMON -an ${INFILE}.2.ts
    ffmpeg -i $IFILE -vf crop=1920:1088:0:1104 $OPT_COMMON -an ${INFILE}.3.ts
    ffmpeg -i $IFILE -vf crop=1920:1088:1920:1104 $OPT_COMMON -an ${INFILE}.4.ts
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Please explain.

Comment: I am testing to playback with 4ea player, that player is machine and connected with ethernet for syncing. But there is not synchronization.   Maybe there is syncing when playback the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to force fixed P/B pattern than you should disable B-frames adaptive algorithm and specify max consecutive B-frames number by using old style global options, for example "-b_strategy 0 -bf 2" for PBBPBBPBBP... pattern. If you also want also fixed I-frames intervals than you need to disable scenecut detection algorithm also, for example "-sc_threshold 0 -g 50" for fixed 50 frames interval between I-frames. With new enough ffmpeg you can also use private libx264 options using -x264opts or -x264-params params.

So for fully fixed frame types pattern you may use any of below command lines (they should be equal):

`ffmpeg -i $INFILE -c:v libx264 -b:v $BITRATE -sc_threshold 0 -g 50 -b_strategy 0 -bf 2 $OUTFILE`

or

`ffmpeg -i $INFILE -c:v libx264 -b:v $BITRATE -x264-params scenecut=0:keyint=50:b-adapt=0:bframes=2 $OUTFILE`